# jsreport handlebars engine and xlsx recipe: how to fill cell with color

Tags: handlebars.js, xlsx, jsreport

I'm trying to fill a cell with *"red"* or *"green"* depending on its value; This is what I tried so far:

```
{{#xlsxAdd 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml' "worksheet.conditionalFormatting"}}
    <conditionalFormatting sqref="G7:M7">
        <cfRule type="cellIs" dxfId="0" priority="1" operator="notBetween">
            <formula>{{productObj.min}}</formula>
            <formula>{{productObj.max}}</formula>
        </cfRule>
    </conditionalFormatting>
{{/xlsxAdd}}
{{#xlsxAdd 'xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml' "worksheet.conditionalFormatting"}}
    <conditionalFormatting sqref="G7:M7">
        <cfRule type="cellIs" dxfId="2" priority="1" operator="between">
            <formula>{{productObj.min}}</formula>
            <formula>{{productObj.max}}</formula>
        </cfRule>
    </conditionalFormatting>
{{/xlsxAdd}}
```

but it seems that the condition `notBetween` always matches the cell, but after I download the file then change the value of the cell, the conditions start to work correctly.

I don't know if reportjs is considering my numbers as **`strings`** since changing the value after downloading the file works perfectly.

-- UPDATE ---

Found this issue: https://github.com/jsreport/jsreport-html-to-xlsx/issues/7

It was a problem with jsreport it's self for adding `'` before my numbers which caused the conditional rendering to fail.
but still, I would appreciate a proper way to fill a cell "NOT" with the conditional formatting so I'll leave the question

--- END UPDATE ---

I also tried to fill with static color this but it didn't work:

```
 {{#xlsxReplace "xl/styles.xml" "styleSheet.fills"}}
    <fills count="5">
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="none"/>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="lightGray"/>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FFBFBFBF"/>
                <bgColor rgb="FFBFBFBF"/>
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FFFF0000"/>
                <bgColor rgb="FFFF0000"/>
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FF00FF00"/>
                <bgColor rgb="FF00FF00"/>
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
    </fills>
{{/xlsxReplace}}
// then adding the cell like this:
 <c t="inlineStr" fillId="3" ><is><t>{{val}}</t></is></c>
```

but still not doing the job, I even tried to add `dxfs` instead of `fills`, if anyone can help me find out what am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its [(zero-based index)](http://officeopenxml.com/SSstyles.php)  so `s="1"` will be the 2nd element `<cellXfs>`

just remember the zero-based index and the counts attribute will be count of elements inside

in the main jsreport file add

```
{{#xlsxReplace "xl/styles.xml"}}
    {#asset style.xml}}
{{/xlsxReplace}}
```

create style.xml and in it add

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<styleSheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
    <fonts count="2" x14ac:knownFonts="2">
        <font>
            <sz val="12" />
            <name val="Calibri" />
            <b />
        </font>
        <font>
            <sz val="12" />
            <name val="Calibri" />
        </font>        
    </fonts>
    <fills count="5">
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="bfbfbf" />
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="bfbfbf" />
            </patternFill>
        </fill>            
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="bfbfbf" />
            </patternFill>
        </fill>    
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FFFF00" />
            </patternFill>
        </fill>
        <fill>
            <patternFill patternType="solid">
                <fgColor rgb="FF0000" />
            </patternFill>
        </fill>      
    </fills>
    <borders count="1">
        <border>
            <left/>
            <right/>
            <top/>
            <bottom/>
            <diagonal/>
        </border>
    </borders>
    <cellXfs count="7">
        <xf />
        <xf fontId="0" fillId="2">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
        <xf fontId="0" fillId="3">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
        <xf fontId="0" fillId="4">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
        <xf fontId="1">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
        <xf fontId="1" fillId="3">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
        <xf fontId="1" fillId="4">
            <alignment horizontal="center" vertical="center" />
        </xf>
    </cellXfs>   
</styleSheet>
```

Comment: even it it stated as zero index it will not work if you pass s="0" please add a a <xf /> first in <cellXfs> and work with it as if it starts with '1' not '0'

Comment: https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/maYvTbXc this might help too

Comment: Nothing is Rendered With a Fill color in the link?

Comment: <c t="inlineStr" s="1"><is><t>{{ this.value }}</t></is></c> you have to pass the "s" number = xf index(from zero) just to be safe add more than 5 in cellXfs

Comment: i suggest to copy these styles / code and work from there since xml can be very tricky  https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/SyupOZ2Dz-5